# jQuery make 'n' class visible when there are multiple divs with that class

Tags: jquery, class, visibility, show-hide

I have 10 `DIV`'s with the class `.sequence-container`

Is it possible to make the 6th and 8th div visible/hidden?

I know you can use

```
$('.sequence-container div:hidden').next();
```

But not sure how to make a specific div visible within the sequence?

Any advice?

Comment: `$('.sequence-container').filter(':lt(5),:gt(7),:eq(6)').hide();` -> http://jsfiddle.net/ka72W/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:eq`

```
$('div.sequence-container:eq(5), div.sequence-container:eq(7)').hide();
```

Edit: `:eq` is zero-based, so the 6th div is actually index 5. Thanks @j08961

Comment: `.eq()` is zero-based, so if he wants the 6th and 8th divs, use 5 and 7 as the indexes.

Comment: Thanks tymeJV - perfect - as an aside if I have the following: `$page = $('.sequence-container div:hidden').next();` - is it possible to set `$page` the the one **after** `.next()` if that makes sense?

Comment: You can just do `.next().next()`

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
  $('.sequence-container')
     .filter(function(i){return (i==5 || i==7);})
     .css('visibility','hidden'); //or use .hide() if you want to make it display:none/block
```

If you are talking about visibility/hidden use the above, if you want to set the display props use `.hide()/.show()` instead of `.css`

Also note that `'.sequence-container div'` will select the div that are descendants of .sequence-container but seems like from your question that is not what you wanted.

You can make this flexible as well.

```
var filter = [6, 8]; //items to be filtered
$('.sequence-container').filter(function (i) {
    return $.inArray((i+1), filter) > -1;
}).hide();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nfC57/)**

Comment: Hi PSL - thanks - I'm struggling a little bit with this one, certainly in terms of terminology.  Effectively, I have code that iterates through and shows the next div on a button click but I need to be able to `skip` a div - if that makes sense.  Just realised my question doesn't convey that very well!  APOLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value) to do exactly that:

```
$(function(){
    $('.sequence-container').css('visibility', function(i){
        //if using display rather than visibility, you can also reference
        // the element by using $(this).hide();
        if(i==5||i==7)
            return 'visible'; 
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uWqvU/